# Import .js file as text and use it inside WebView injectedJavaScript in react-native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, expo

I have a file `content.js` that includes some JavaScript code that I want to inject inside a WebView using `injectedJavaScript`.

I tried:

```js
    fetch('./content.js').then((result) => {
      result = result.text();
      this.setState(previousState => (
        {contentScript: result}
      ));
    });
```

But it doesn't get the right file.

```js
const contentScript = require('./content.js');
```

This works, but it evals the JavaScript straight away and I can't seem to find a way to convert it to string before it gets executed.

A solution is to just make copy the code of `content.js` into a string, but that would be pretty annoying when I want to edit the code...

Does anyone know a better solution for this?
I still have no solution to this for almost a week. :(

Comment: Add file-loaded rule to webpack and target this file

Comment: @deathangel908 Could you explain me a little bit more about this? I'd also like to add that I'm using EXPO.

Answer (score 3):

Since expo is using [webpack](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/customizing-webpack/) you can customize it. Webpack has a [loaders](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/) section you might be interested in. And the loader you need is called [raw-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/). So when you require some file, webpack runs this file against the chain of loaders it has in config. And by default all `.js` files are bundled into `index.js` that gets executed when you run your app. Instead you need the content of the file that `raw-loader` exactly does. It will insert something like

```
module.contentScript = function() { return "console.log('Hello world!')"}
```

instead of:

```
module.contentScript = function() { console.log('Hello World'}}
```

So you need:

```
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

and inside your code:

```
require('raw-loader!./content.js');
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be the solution, but I get `Unable to resolve "raw-loader!./content.js" from "App.js"` when using `require('raw-loader!./content.js')`

Comment: Did you install raw-loader? Try to hardcode filename in webpack.conf, try to play with path, e.g. instead of specifying the relative path to current component, specify realtive to project root, or relative to system root. Try to target different file type than js. e.g. txt. It's hard to tell what's exactly wrong. Should work out of the box though.

Comment: sadly I can't get it to work... It detects the file if I just specify `./content.js`, but `raw-loader!./content.js` doesn't work.
`Unable to resolve module !!raw-laoder!./content.js from F:\\Projects\\x\\x\App.js: Module !!raw-loader!./content.js does not exist in the Hase module map.`

Comment: Question also, do you have to install and run anything else apart from just installing `webpack`? Do I run it in some way or what? I have never used it...

Comment: just installing `raw-loader` should do fine.

Comment: Then sadly it doesn't work. I tried a few things, but failed. I have no idea how I'd make this to work.. :( Please let me know if you figure something out. Also here is my `package.json` https://pastebin.com/2ge3zw7W

Comment: Could you please create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: This won't fully work, because I heavily stripped my code, but you have a decent example I think. https://pastebin.com/2XYpyu9b

Comment: Wow, is contentScript a path to a file or content of the file?

Comment: It should be the content of the file, but in pure text. Because I want to use it in `injectedJavascript` and that evals text to JS.

Answer (score 1):

## Important update re: the below

I have egg on my face, it turns out the below does not work in the default Metro bundler (I thought it was bult on top of Webpack, it isn't) and in my situation, it gave the illusion for a while it was working. The following will work if using Webpack to bundle for the web, which React Native *does* support, (but would be pointless for this scenario as `WebView` doesn't support the web anyway), or if using another bundler based on webpack with support for loaders, like the currently in development [RePack](https://github.com/callstack/repack) (Note: this doesn't support Expo *yet*). I will leave my answer below for reference in case anyone using RePack or a future bundler comes along.

My workaround for now involves making a custom build pipeline in my package.json to copy all my files to a build folder and then transform files with a .raw.js extension to a string and precede it with `export default` [using a script](https://github.com/Spatchy/ReddiSteddi/blob/1267ea1df4394bc2c8799c341466d5b495b84553/.build_scripts/transpileStrings.js) before executing the real build on that folder.

### (June 2023) An expansion of @deathangel908's answer

For those that don't want to specify the loader every time they import a given file, you can use pattern matching in your `webpack.config.js` file. I renamed the JS file I wanted to inject to `myscript.raw.js` - your editor, eslint, etc will still see it as a regular js file but you can now configure webpack to recognise any filename ending with `.raw.js` and use the raw loader:

**(make sure you install it with `npm i --save-dev raw-loader`)**

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.raw.js$/i,
        use: "raw-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

You can now import the file as you would with any other JS file, but it will be treated as a string:

```
// App.js

import myscript from "./myscript.raw.js" // myscript is just a string!
```

**You may recieve a strange error at runtime if using the string directly:** `error while updating property injectedJavaScript`, to counteract this, just wrap the variable in a string literal:

```
// App.js

<WebView
      // ...
      injectedJavaScript={`${myscript}`}
/>
```

### Important info for TypeScript users

First, you'll want to add your `.raw.js` files to your typescript `exclude` block as these injectable files can only be pure JS and you don't want TypeScript to throw annyoing errors:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
    // ...
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "babel.config.js",
        "metro.config.js",
        "*.raw.js"
    ]
    // ...
}
```

Secondly, TypeScript will throw an error on your import: `Could not find a declaration file for module 'myscript'. '/path/to/myscript.raw.js' implicitly has an 'any' type`
To fix this you must create a declarations (`.d.ts`) file somewhere in your source, I just made a file in the root of my repository called `declarations.d.ts`:

```
// declarations.d.ts

declare module "*.raw.js" {
  const contents: string
  export default contents
}
```